# "Access denied" error when setting up Oracle 10g

Tags: windows-xp, oracle-10g

I have installed Oracle 10g on my Windows XP SP3 system. When I try to add TNSORANAMES.ORA to the ADMIN folder, I get the following message:

```
ERROR:-ACCESS DENIED.
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Add the particular user to `ora_dba` group by going to `local users and groups` settings.